# MYSQL Insert Trigger (Insert Multiple values)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a use case

Table 1 has data as below

```
**CID**  **COMPANY**
  1      CompanyA
  2      CompanyB
  3      CompanyC
```

Table 2 has data as below

```
  **ID****COMPANY****PERSON**
    1  CompanyB  Sachin
    2  CompanyB  Kohli
    3  CompanyC  Dhoni
    4  CompanyA  Raina
    5  CompanyA  Shikar
```

data should be inserted in Table 3 , whenever an insert occurs in table 1, i need to select values from Table 2 based on COMPANY and insert the data into table 3 as follows

Table 3

```
 **ID****CID****PERSON**
    1    1    Raina    
    2    1    Shikar
    3    2    Sachin
    4    2    Kohli
    5    3    Dhoni
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? What doesn't work with what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution, using [`CREATE TRIGGER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html):

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER insert_table3 AFTER INSERT ON table1
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO table3 (CID, PERSON) 
            SELECT table1.CID, table2.PERSON 
            FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.COMPANY = table2.COMPANY 
            WHERE CID = NEW.CID
            GROUP BY table2.PERSON;
    END;
|
```